# Finding Avg on multiple Date Dimension Hierarchies

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, mdx, dimensional-modeling, ssas-2012

I have a cube, and within that cube there is a date dimension which has the following attributes

**Calendar Year, Calendar Month-Year, Fiscal Year, Fiscal Year-Quarter, Date**

Now with these attributes I have two user defined hierarchies, they are as follows
**Calendar Hierarchy** which has Calendar Year, Calendar Month-Year, Date

The second user defined hierarchy is 
**Fiscal Hierarchy** which has Fiscal Year, Fiscal Year-Quarter, Calendar Month Year and Date

I want to know the average sales so I created a measure which goes

```
Member [Measures].[Sales Daily Avg]
AS Avg ( Descendants ( [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, [Date].[Calendar].[Date] ), CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[Total Sales] , 0) )
```

This works great when running something like

```
SELECT {
[Measures].[Sales Daily Avg],
} ON COLUMNS,
{ [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].Members } ON ROWS
FROM 
[SalesCube]
```

This will work if I use **[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month-Year].Members** but it will not work on my fiscal hierarchy attributes except for Calendar Month-Year.  How can I modify my measure so that it will accept the fiscal year hierarchy attributes.

I tried cross joining by the fiscal year, because if the set is empty, it will just evaluate the one that is being used.  But it just doesnt work for me ( I am assuming sytnax might be the issue).

Sorry guys, I am really new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of calculated member to :

```
CREATE Member [Measures].[Sales Daily Avg]
AS 
IIF
  (
   NOT([Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Date].[Fiscal].[All])
   ,
   Avg 
     ( 
      Descendants 
                (
                 [Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER, 
                 [Date].[Fiscal].[Date] 
                )
     ,
     CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[Total Sales] , 0) 
    )
   ,
   IIF
     (
      NOT([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Date].[Calendar].[All])
      ,
      Avg 
        ( 
         Descendants 
                (
                 [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, 
                 [Date].[Calendar].[Date] 
                )
        ,
        CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[Total Sales] , 0)
        ),
        NULL //Change this to whatever you want in case none of the hierarchies 'Calendar' or 'Fiscal' is involved.
     )
     )
```

Basically this will first check if any member from "Fiscal" hierachy is in scope or not. If so, it will average out on the Fiscal dates for the selected member. If the first condition is not met, it further checks if any member from "Calendar" hierarchy is in scope. If so, it works similarly over "Calendar" hierarchy. Finally if none of the hierarchy's members are in scope, it yields `NULL`(you might rethink and put as per your requirement).

NOTE: when the `currentmember` of any hierarchy is the `All` member, that means that hierarchy is not in scope(not part of slicer or the axes)

Comment: I am getting #Error.  Your conditions look like they are working great, but when it comes to execute the AVG functions, something seems to not work. I have tested the avg function outside of the IFF function, and they work fun, as soon as they are in their, it yields an #Error.

Comment: It could be anything ranging from a typo to a standard syntax error. I hadn't tested it yet. Let me.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks alot. Not only was your code correct, your explanation was very educational.  MDX is a pain to learn.

Comment: does this measure work if we have `[Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS` ON ROWS ?

Comment: @SouravA +1 for your answer. Only problem though is when you select more than one member in the filter (say two calendar years), Excel will send them in a sub query (sub-cube) and SSAS won't be aware that calendar year is being used causing it to return null.